# Forward named pipe over ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, named-pipes

I'd like to forward a named pipe over SSH, from remote Windows machine to a local machine. The remote Windows machine is running `sshd` (OpenSSH). The pipe I want to forward is for the Docker Engine API, although that shouldn't matter.

To forward an equivalent Unix domain socket from a remote Unix machine, I'd run (and this works):

```
ssh -NL localhost:2374:/var/run/docker.sock user@host
```

The equivalent for a remote Windows machine named pipe would be:

```
ssh -NL localhost:2373://./pipe/docker_engine Administrator@windows-host
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I'm using [PowerShell/OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH). Running the sshd in debug mode, I see this when trying to connect through the tunnel:

```
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: pipe - read end: handle:0000000000000244, io:000001C199D59F20, fd:4
debug1: pipe - write end: handle:0000000000000238, io:000001C199D3F5F0, fd:6
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype direct-streamlocal@openssh.com rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: server_request_direct_streamlocal: originator ::1 port 59191, target //./pipe/docker_engine
debug1: socket - socket() ERROR:47, io:000001C199D593F0
socket: Unknown error
connect to //./pipe/docker_engine port -2 failed: Unknown error
debug1: server_input_channel_open: failure direct-streamlocal@openssh.com
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype direct-streamlocal@openssh.com rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: server_request_direct_streamlocal: originator ::1 port 59192, target //./pipe/docker_engine
debug1: socket - socket() ERROR:47, io:000001C199D593F0
socket: Unknown error
connect to //./pipe/docker_engine port -2 failed: Unknown error
debug1: server_input_channel_open: failure direct-streamlocal@openssh.com
```

Answer (score 3):

To start with, you've swapped the order of the first two arguments local address and port) in the second example:

```
ssh -NL localhost:2374:/var/run/docker.sock user@host
ssh -NL 2374:localhost:\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine user@host
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first form is correct:

```
    ssh -NL localhost:2374:.... user@host
```

Concerning the path to the named pipe, the OpenSSH `ssh` utility will only treat a forward specification field as a pathname if it contains a "/" (forward slash). Replacing one or more of the (escaped) backslashes with a forward slash should get ssh to recognize it as a path:

```
ssh -NL localhost:2374:\\\\.\\pipe/docker_engine user@host
```

I don't know if the resulting path would be a valid pathname on the remote system. If the remote server is Cygwin OpenSSH, then it ought to accept pathnames in [Cygwin-supported formats](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames), including [UNC paths](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths). You could try replacing all of the "\" pairs with "/":

```
ssh -NL localhost:2374://./pipe/docker_engine user@host
```

Comment: `2374:localhost:\\\\.\\pipe/docker_engine` also gets the same error

Comment: same for `'2374:localhost://./pipe/docker_engine`

Comment: thanks for catching that - I've tried with your suggestions, and have also added additional details and debug info

Answer (score 0):

Just researched this topic and found out, that it's not supported yet. Please check status of these tickets:

- https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/435
- https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/pull/433